# Using Pattern and Matcher to search for special characters (Example: $)

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Apologies if this has already been answered.

I am using the following code to search for a substring:

```
String subject = "ABC"
String subString = "AB"
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(subString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(subject);

while (matcher.find()){
//Matched
}
```

But when my subject string contains a $ in the beginning, it does not work since it is a special character.

```
String subject = "$ABC"
String subString = "$"
```

How does one handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By escaping the special character in the `subString`. Like,

```
String subString = "\\$";
```

*or* telling the `Pattern` to match literals. Like,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(subString, Pattern.LITERAL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: If you don't know in advance what you're searching for, [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

There are few meta characters in regex. And some of them which are supported by regex in java are

```
( ) [ ] { { \ ^ $ | ? * + . < > - = !
```

So **$** is a indeed meta character here. The meta character conveys special meaning to the regex engine and hence can't be use literally. So in order to use them you have to combine them with escape character which is backslash **\**

So `String subject = "\\$ABC"
    String subString = "\\$"`

would do. Java uses double backslash instead of single for escape character unlike the other regex engine.

Comment: "Java uses double backslash instead of single" is incorrect;  Java uses single backslash just like other regexes.  For example, if you look at your "subject" or "substring" variables in the debugger as the program is running, you would find the string value contains a single backslash.  The need for the double-backslash is purely to escape the backslash for a String value (similar to "\n", etc), not for the Regex.

Comment: yes. My bad I just forget it is the case of escape character